# Is there a notable difference between 'result is T' vs 'typeof(T).IsInstanceOfType(result)'?

Tags: c#, types, instance

Both of the following statements test if some object `x` is of type `T`.  Is there any difference that one should be aware of performance-wise?

```
var result1 = x is T;
var result2 = typeof(T).IsInstanceOfType(x);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Ooops!. Typo. Corrected.  And no specific use. Just a curiosity-type question.

Comment: And why was this voted down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [`IsInstanceOfType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isinstanceoftype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is a method that takes an `object`, value types would be boxed. Operator `is`, on the other hand, will not perform boxing.

Using the first approach is better when you know `T` at compile time, either as a specific type or a generic type parameter. The second approach is for situations when your code obtains the type at run-time, because the first approach does not apply:

```
Type typeKnownAtRuntime = ...
var result2 = typeKnownAtRuntime.IsInstanceOfType(x); // This works
var incorrect = x is typeKnownAtRuntime;   // This does not compile
```

Comment: You mean [it's boxed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx).  You might want to elaborate on that to make it clear why that's bad.

Comment: Is there ever a reason to use `IsInstanceOfType` over `is`?  You just gave a great case for the reverse and now I'm wondering why I'd ever use the former.

Comment: Actually, your edit really doesn't explain why.  What compile-time support do you get? It still takes an object. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @MarqueIV I added an example with code to illustrate when `IsInstanceOfType` becomes the only viable approach.

Comment: Perfect explanation.  Thanks! Accepted.